# How to point to specific DNS with custom port in Java

Tags: java, dns, service-discovery, microservices, consul

I'm using DNS Interface of Consul. It is available at `localhost, port 8600`. How can I point to this DNS in my Java program?

So far I can only change the address to localhost using Java system properties

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", "localhost");
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");
```

But I could not find the way for the port 8600. Please help?

This is the command to query for `web.service.consul`

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 web.service.consul
```

Comment: Perhaps you can set a dns pseudo url like described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-dns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's an option for you, but you could connect to the Consul agent using one of the libraries (e.g. [consul-client](https://github.com/OrbitzWorldwide/consul-client)) and utilize it's capabilities for service discovery.